# Looking for an alternative part for a refrigerator

Tags: cooling

I have an old Samsung 2-door fridge. It's model is RS20NRSV. The damper control window isn't working anymore and it seems like finding parts for this model is difficult.

EDIT 1:
From looking at a manual I [found online](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/697844/Samsung-Rs20ncsl.html?page=3#manual), the damper motor model is DA31-00043B.

Is there a compatible alternative that I can use to get similar functionality?

I've been seeing results that indicate the parts no longer availabe/manufactured.
Eg: https://spares.bigwarehouse.com.au/product_info.php?cPath=143_453_84389&products_id=1534011,

Part of what led me to the question is that there are parts like [this](https://www.repairclinic.com/PartDetail/Damper-Control-Assembly/DA31-00071G/2313947), and [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Genuine-Samsung-Fridge-Freezer-Air-Damper-Motor-DA31-00218B-NSBA001TH1/114747960081?_trkparms=aid%3D1110006%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIM%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20140131123730%26meid%3Dafb87dc04d554d1b839b7b6ae5a5edc9%26pid%3D100167%26rk%3D6%26rkt%3D15%26sd%3D122975861034%26itm%3D114747960081%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D5411%26algv%3DDefaultOrganic%26brand%3DSamsung&_trksid=p5411.c100167.m2940&autorefresh=true) - which are not the same as the model I identified above, so I don't if they will work.

Comment: Where have you looked for parts? I plugged that modem number in google along with damper and compatible parts came up. It could be the damper motor, control board, or a thermistor.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, however I agree with gunner.

Comment: Edited question, I understand about not providing product recommends, can delete question if that's what this may be boiling down to.

Comment: One of your links to an alternate part shows the part and its connector quite clearly on a calibrated background.  You should remove the part from your fridge and compare it to those photos to determine whether it might fit.  Then it's just a toss of the dice.